# Need to get the Value from URL asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting a strange value in quick watch. I need to get the id value which is 222 from the URL. My code in the watch window is `Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values`. My actual URL is **http://localhost:50983/Measurement/Create/222**

The value I get from the above line of code is

[image: Quick watch window]

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Measurement",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Measurement", action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional }


            );
```

Comment: Pls show some code what you have wrote

Comment: and code from ../App_Start\RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Try to store the value of `RouteData.Values["id"]` into a variable and check

Comment: @Nisfan I am basically redirecting from a view to a controller. Index View to Create Controller with an id from Index View 222.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale but I am redirecting from CustomerControllers Index View to Measurements Controller Create view with an id. where do I set it ?

Comment: in Measurements  controller

Comment: @AbidAli Does your method look like this? -> `public ActionResult Create(int id){}`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yes.

Comment: Then have you noticed that the value of id from URL is available in the method's parameter `int id`

Comment: (1) Your route named Measurement is never used, you can delete it. Any URL it could match will instead get matched first by your Default route. (2) If you *reliably* get this strange effect of id=Create then either you have more route definitions in your `RouteConfig` above the Default route you have shown us, or you are coming from an action which has parameters that include (string id) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had an action="Create" due to which I was getting the Id which is an Optional Parameter was set to Create. When I set the action with the value Measurement/Create/222, then I was getting the Id value with 222.

So, I replace the form tag with @Html.BeginForm and pass the route values with the the id.